# How can I resubmit v1.0 as v1.1 so I can change screenshots, keywords etc in iTunes connect?

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store-connect

I don't need to make any changes to the binary, I just want to refresh screenshots, keywords, and other metadata. We are currently on v1.0 (ready for sale) and I know I would need to a v1.1 build in order to create a new submission. Is there perhaps a way renaming v1.0 as v1.1, or cloning it and naming v1.1?

I'm not technical, so was hoping someone could explain if there is a method to do this without engaging my developer. Any help would be tremendous appreciated!

Comment: I could be wrong, but IIRC you don't need to create a new submission to edit metadata. Just click the v 1.0 entry on the left panel and edit the data there. Creating v 1.1 would require a binary built with that version.

Comment: there are certain metadata fields you can submit without needing to submit a new build https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/ChangingAppMetadata.html ( Refer to Viewing and Editing Shared App Information section). For updating screenshot you need to submit a new build with updated build version. You will need developer to update and upload new build

Answer (score 1):

You have to upload a new binary file of your app to change information such as the app version. The description, however, can be edited without submitting a new build.

Go to your `My App`, select the app you want to edit, click `1.0 ready for sale` under `App Store` tab. There you can see all of the information, including keywords and screenshots etc. The app description, version feature, as well as other contact info can be edited, while the keywords and app version is locked. Remember to save your changes after editing by clicking the `save` button on the the upper-right corner.

[image]

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to upload new build with changed build number, application version and create version in iTunes connect with screenshots and other stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Exactly what ghkaren said! You just have to go to xcode and in the general screen with the bundle identifier you can go under and see version and build. I believe for a new update you need to change version and then post a new update!